# Query regarding Naive Bayes algorithm in package e1071 R

Tags: r, statistics, bayesian, naivebayes

Below is the training dataset that I am using for Naive Bayes implementation in R(using e1071 package) where: X,Y,Z are the different classes and V1,V2,V3,V4,V5 are the attributes:-

```
Class   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
X       Yes Yes No  Yes Yes
X       Yes Yes No  No  Yes
X       Yes Yes No  No  Yes
X       Yes Yes No  No  Yes
X        No Yes No  No  Yes
X        No Yes No  No  Yes
X        No Yes No  No  Yes
X        No No  No  No  No
X        No No  No  No  No
X        No No  No  No  No
X        No No  No  No  No
X        No No  No  No  No
X        No No  No  No  No
X        No No  No  No  No
X        No No  No  No  No
X        No No  No  No  No
Y       Yes Yes Yes No  Yes
Y        No No  No  No  Yes
Y        No No  No  No  Yes
Y        No No  No  No  No
Y        No No  No  No  No
Y        No No  No  No  No
Y        No No  No  No  No
Z        No Yes Yes No  Yes
Z        No No  No  No  Yes
Z        No No  No  No  Yes
Z        No No  No  No  No
Z        No No  No  No  No
Z        No No  No  No  No
Z        No No  No  No  No
```

The prior probabilities for the above dataset are X->0.5333333 Y->0.2333333 Z->0.2333333

and the conditional probabilities are :-

```
V1
Y          No       Yes
   X 0.7500000 0.2500000
   Y 0.8571429 0.1428571
   Z 1.0000000 0.0000000

V2
Y          No       Yes
   X 0.5625000 0.4375000
   Y 0.8571429 0.1428571
   Z 0.8571429 0.1428571

V3
 Y          No       Yes
   X 1.0000000 0.0000000
   Y 0.8571429 0.1428571
   Z 0.8571429 0.1428571

V4
 Y       No    Yes
   X 0.9375 0.0625
   Y 1.0000 0.0000
   Z 1.0000 0.0000

V5
 Y          No       Yes
   X 0.5625000 0.4375000
   Y 0.5714286 0.4285714
   Z 0.5714286 0.4285714
```

**Case 1:- Laplace smoothing not used**

I want to find out in which class does V3 belong to, given value Yes. So I have my test data as :-

```
V3
Yes
```

So, I have to find out probability of each class ie, Probability(X| V3=Yes), Probability(Y| V3=Yes),Probability(Z| V3=Yes) and take the maximum out of the three. Now,

Probability(X| V3=Yes)= Probability(X) * Probability(V3=Yes|X)/ P(V3)

From the conditional probability mentioned above, we know that Probability(V3=Yes|X)=0
So, Probability(X| V3=Yes) should be 0 and  Probability(Y| V3=Yes),Probability(Z| V3=Yes) should be 0.5 each.

But in R output is different. From the package e1071 I have used naiveBayes function. Below is the code and its corresponding output:-

```
#model_nb<-naiveBayes(Class~.,data = train,laplace=0)
#results<-predict(model_nb,test,type = "raw")
#print(results)

#         X         Y         Z
#[1,] 0.5714286 0.2142857 0.2142857
```

Can someone please explain as to why such is the output in R?

**Case 2:- Laplace smoothing used**

Same scenario as Case1 w.r.t. Test Data, only difference being laplace used is 1. So, again I have to find out probability of each class ie, Probability(X| V3=Yes), Probability(Y| V3=Yes),Probability(Z| V3=Yes) and take the maximum out of the three.

Below are the conditional probabilities after laplace smoothing(k=1)

```
V1
Y          No       Yes
   X 0.7222222 0.2777778
   Y 0.7777778 0.2222222
   Z 0.8888889 0.1111111

V2
Y          No       Yes
   X 0.5555556 0.4444444
   Y 0.7777778 0.2222222
   Z 0.7777778 0.2222222

V3
Y          No        Yes
   X 0.94444444 0.05555556
   Y 0.77777778 0.22222222
   Z 0.77777778 0.22222222

V4
Y          No       Yes
   X 0.8888889 0.1111111
   Y 0.8888889 0.1111111
   Z 0.8888889 0.1111111

V5
Y          No       Yes
   X 0.5555556 0.4444444
   Y 0.5555556 0.4444444
   Z 0.5555556 0.4444444
```

From naive bayes definition,

Probability(X| V3=Yes)= Probability(X) * Probability(V3=Yes|X)/ P(V3)

Probability(Y| V3=Yes)= Probability(Y) * Probability(V3=Yes|X)/ P(V3)

Probability(Z| V3=Yes)= Probability(Z) * Probability(V3=Yes|X)/ P(V3)

After Calculation I have,

Probability(X| V3=Yes)= 0.53 * 0.05555556 / P(V3)=0.029/P(V3)

Probability(Y| V3=Yes)= 0.23 * 0.22222222 / P(V3)=0.051/P(V3)

Probability(Z| V3=Yes)= 0.23 * 0.22222222 / P(V3)=0.051/P(V3)

From the above calculation, there should be a tie between class Y and Z. But in R output is different. Class X is being shown as output class. Below is the code and its corresponding output:-

```
#model_nb<-naiveBayes(Class~.,data = train,laplace=1)
#results<-predict(model_nb,test,type = "raw")
#print(results)


#        X         Y         Z
#[1,] 0.5811966 0.2094017 0.2094017
```

Again, can someone please explain why is such the output in R? Am I going wrong anywhere with my calculation?

Also, need some explanation on how P(V3) would be calculated when laplace smoothing is done.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using just one sample for the test dataset, with only one value of `V3`. If you give a bit more test data you get sensible/expected results (focusing only on your **case 1**):

```
test <- data.frame(V3=c("Yes", "No"))
predict(model_nb, test, type="raw")
               X         Y         Z
[1,] 0.007936508 0.4960317 0.4960317
[2,] 0.571428571 0.2142857 0.2142857
```

Note you don't get exactly 0, 0.5, 0.5 for V3="Yes", since the function is using a threshold -which you can adjust, do `?predict.naiveBayes` for more info.

The problem is actually due to the internal implementation of `predict.naiveBayes` (the source code is at CRAN repository). I'm not going to go into all the details, but basically I've debugged the function, and in a certain step there is this line,

```
newdata <- data.matrix(newdata)
```

which will later decide which column of the conditional probabilities to use. With your original data the data.matrix looks like this:

```
data.matrix(data.frame(V3="Yes"))
     V3
[1,]  1
```

thus it later assumes that the conditional probabilities were to be taken from column 1, i.e values 1.0000000, 0.8571429 and 0.8571429 for V3="No", and that's why you were getting results as if V3 was actually "No".

However,

```
data.matrix(data.frame(V3=c("Yes", "No")))
     V3
[1,]  2
[2,]  1
```

gives column 2 of the conditional probabilities when V3 is "Yes", and thus you get the right result.

I'm pretty sure your **case 2** is just analogous.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT after comments:** I guess the easier way to solve it would be to put all the data in one data.frame, and select the indexes you use for training/testing your model. Many functions accept `subset` to select the data you use for training, and `naiveBayes` is no exception. However, for `predict.naiveBayes` you have to select the index. Something like this.

```
all_data <- rbind(train, c(NA, NA, NA, "Yes", NA, NA))
trainIndex <- 1:30
model_nb <- naiveBayes(Class~., data=all_data, laplace=0, subset=trainIndex)
predict(model_nb, all_data[-trainIndex,], type="raw")
```

gives the expected result.

```
               X         Y         Z
[1,] 0.007936508 0.4960317 0.4960317
```

Note that this works because in this case when you do the `data.matrix` operation you get the right result.

```
data.matrix(all_data[-trainIndex,])
   Class V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
31    NA NA NA  2 NA NA
```

**EDIT2 after comments:** Some more details on why this is happening.

When you define your `test` dataframe including only one value equal to "No", the conversion performed by `data.matrix` has actually no way to know that your variable `V3` has 2 possible values, "Yes" and "No". `test$V3` is actually a factor:

```
test <- data.frame(V3="Yes")
class(test$V3)
[1] "factor"
```

and as said it has only one level (no way for the data.frame to know there are actually 2)

```
levels(test$V3)
[1] "Yes"
```

The implementation of `data.matrix`, as you can see in the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.matrix.html), uses the levels of the factor:

> Factors and ordered factors are replaced by their internal codes.

Thus when converting test to `data.matrix` it interprets there's only one possible value of the factor and decodes it,

```
data.matrix(test)
     V3
[1,]  1
```

However, when you do the trick of putting training and test into the same dataframe, the factor levels are properly defined.

```
levels(all_data$V3)
[1] "No"  "Yes"
```

The result would be the same if you did this:

```
test <- data.frame(V3=factor("Yes", levels=levels(all_data$V3)))
test
   V3
1 Yes
levels(test$V3)
[1] "No"  "Yes"
data.matrix(test)
     V3
[1,]  2
```

Comment: Yes, it helps! In my case I would be interested more often than not to find such instances P(Class|Attribute="Yes") only. But due to internal implementation of predict.naiveBayes I would have to provide both the values of attributes ie, Yes & No to get the desired result (of Yes in my case). Any way of getting around this problem?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more practical solution than providing two values. If you still have doubts or problems, let me know. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. I liked the part of- put all the values in one data.frame and use indexes to train/test a model. Just one last doubt:-
_When the test data is like_  `V3= Yes`         
   
`data.matrix(data.frame(V3="Yes"))
           V3
[1,]  1       #Here column being taken is 1`      
    
_When the test data is like_
`all_data <- rbind(train, c(NA, NA, NA, "Yes", NA, NA))`
`data.matrix(all_data[-trainIndex,])
   
         Class V1 V2 V3 V4 V5

             31    NA NA NA  2 NA NA     #Here column being taken is 2`


Why so?

Comment: Hi. I've updated the answer with some more explanations. Hope it is clearer now. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Got the picture. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and it really is **all about FACTORS!**  You must synchronise factor levels between the training data and the new data presented for prediction. *(As Rinzcig covered in 'edit 2' above.)*

The Naive Bayes function in e1071 converts all character data to factors.  You must control this conversion otherwise you'll get unexpected results.

It's just this line of code you needed:

```
test <- data.frame(V3=factor("Yes", levels=levels(all_data$V3)))
```

You can see that I had the [same issue and solution here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45603450/unexpected-result-from-e1071-naive-bayes)